# HDFS File Encoding Converter

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, encoding, hdfs

I'm trying to convert an HDFS file from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1`.

I've written a small Java program :

```java
String theInputFileName="my-utf8-input-file.csv";
String theOutputFileName="my-iso8859-output-file.csv";
Charset inputCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
Charset outputCharset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;

try (
    final FSDataInputStream in = theFileSystem.open(new Path(theInputFileName)) ;
    final FSDataOutputStream out = theFileSystem.create(new Path(theOutputFileName))
)        
{
    try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, inputCharset)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            out.write(line.getBytes(this.outputCharset));
            out.write(this.lineSeparator.getBytes(this.outputCharset));
        }
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e)
{
    RddFileWriter.LOGGER.error(e, "Exception on file '%s'", theFileNameOutput);
}
```

This code is executed through a Hadoop Cluster using `Spark` (the output data is usually provided by a RDD)

To simplify my issue I have removed RDD/Datasets parts to work direcly on HDFS File.

When I execute the code :

- **Localy** on my DEV computer : It Works !, local output file is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`
- on **EDGE serve**r : via spark-submit command using HDFS Files It Works ! HDFS output file is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`
- on **Datanode via oozie** : It doesn't work :-( : HDFS outfile is encoded in `UTF-8` instead of `ISO-8859-1`

I don't understand what properties (or something else) may be causing the change in behavior

Versions :

- Hadoop : v2.7.3
- Spark : v2.2.0
- Java : 1.8

Looking forward to your help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the source of my problem.

The input file on the cluster was corrupted, the whole file did not have a constant and consistent encoding.

External data are aggregated daily and recently the encoding has been changed from ISO to UTF8 without notification...

To put it more simply:

- the start contained bad conversion « Ã© Ãª Ã¨ » instead of « é ê è »
- the end was correctly encoded

We have split, fixed the encoding and merged the data to repair the input.

The final code works fine.

```java
private void changeEncoding(
            final Path thePathInputFileName,final Path thePathOutputFileName,
            final Charset theInputCharset,  final Charset theOutputCharset,
            final String theLineSeparator
        ) {
    try (
        final FSDataInputStream in = this.fileSystem.open(thePathInputFileName);
        final FSDataOutputStream out = this.fileSystem.create(thePathOutputFileName);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, theInputCharset));
        final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, theOutputCharset));) {
        
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.write(theLineSeparator);
        }
        
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e, "Exception on file '%s'", theOutputFileName);
    }
}
```

Stop your research !
;-)